# How to get the list functions defined in a source file

Tags: c++, c

For example i am having following source file.

```
#define xyz 50
int global_var = 45;

struct abd
{
type data1;
type1 data2;
type2 data3;
}

int function1(arg1, arg2, arg3)
{

  //statements

}

user_defined_type function2 ( arg4,arg5,arg6)
{

//statements

}

void function3 ( argx, argy,argz)
{

 //statements

}
```

How can I  get the output as **function1**, **function2**, **function3**.
I tried to read the file using perl, but i am not able to get logic to extract functions from entire source file.

Comment: This is not a freelancers portal but Q&A site so read how to ask question etc [here](https://stackoverflow.com/tour)

Answer (score 5):

I would not go into parsing of source code, as there too many intricacies of C language syntax to cover this. Instead compile it into object file (`gcc` has `-c` option for that) and then use [`nm`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/nm) command to obtain defined symbols, e.g.:

```
$ nm check.o 
0000000000000000 T function1
000000000000000f T function2
000000000000001e T function3
0000000000000000 D global_var
```

From this point you can extract symbols with `T` type utilizing whatever parsing tool that you want.

```
"T"
"t" The symbol is in the text (code) section.
```